# How do I use Microsoft Application Insights with NLog (Target cannot be found: 'ApplicationInsights')

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

I am using `Microsoft Application Insights` for my Web Application. I used the Application Insights TraceListener NuGet package for logging. That worked perfectly.

Now I would like to switch to NLog. I added the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget` NuGet package and added a new NLog target in my NLog configuration file:

```
<target name='ai' xsi:type='ApplicationInsights' />
```

NLog throws an exception:

```
Target cannot be found: 'ApplicationInsights'
```

I also tried adding the assembly via extensions like so:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
</extensions>
```

But it did not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget.dll is correctly copied to the output folder?  Have you tried to register the target from code with: `ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition("ApplicationInsightsTarget", typeof(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget.ApplicationInsightsTarget));`?

Comment: I have already checked that the NLog target dll and all the depending dll's are indeed in the final bin folder. But I will try to add it programmatically as you suggested. Good idea!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution: (thanks to @nemesv for the tip)

Programmatically add the target with

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition(
    "ApplicationInsightsTarget", 
    typeof(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget.ApplicationInsightsTarget)
);
```

and use it with

```
<target name='ai' xsi:type='ApplicationInsightsTarget' />
```

Comment: seems they all map to trace in application insight, any idea how to map it to exception?

Comment: What a nonsense! Documentation says nothing about that extra RegisterDefinition call. I was struggling with this as well. Thank you very much for this solution!

Comment: I am trying to register and log programmatically. But the logs are not getting logged. I have raised a question in stackoverflow and its up for a toss. I tried with internal log and it is showing no error what so error. Here's the link to my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401441/application-insights-configuration-web-api

Comment: @Bargitta when you send an exception with a `LogXXX` call, it will register the telemetry as exception.

Answer (score 8):

Or you can programmatically specify the target:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition(
            "ai", 
            typeof(ApplicationInsightsTarget)
        );
ApplicationInsightsTarget aiTarget = new ApplicationInsightsTarget();
aiTarget.InstrumentationKey = "your_key";
aiTarget.Name = "ai";
config.AddTarget("ai", aiTarget);
LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else stumbles over this:
The correct target type is `ApplicationInsightsTarget` not `ApplicationInsights`.

This works fine:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
</extensions>    
<targets>
    <target name="ai" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" />
</targets>
```

No need to add the target by code.

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/tree/main/LOGGING#nlog