# Adding logs on the Azure Application insights from the ASP.Net MVC framework 4.6.2

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

I wanted to add logs on the Azure Application Insights in my application, ASP.Net Web application MVC, .Net Framework is 4.6.2.

I do have added references to below nuget packages

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

I do have added below code in Global.asax.cs in the applicatin_start
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());

Inside HomeController.cs, I have added below code, but it is giving me below error at the line _logger.LogTrace()

**Error**

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: logger'

**Code**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    public HomeController()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<HomeController>>();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        _logger.LogTrace("Some trace message from Version 462");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you need to add Application Insights. Below are the steps you can follow to add Application Insights to your Application.

1. Navigate to your  **Project**  >>  **Add Application Insights Telemetry**  >>  **Application Insights Sdk (local)**  >>  **Next**  >>  **Finish**  >>  **Close**.
2. You can register the initializer through `applicationinsights.config`  file, while Adding Application Insights automatically we need to add the instrumentation key to  `ApplicationInsights.config`  before closing the  `</ApplicationInsights>`  tag file.

   ```cs
   <InstrumentationKey>"your-instrumentation-key-goes-here"</InstrumentationKey>
   ```

   [image]

   OR

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       // ...
       TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
   }
   ```

   And while logging in from your Home Controller try

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
           public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
           {
               _logger = logger;
           }

           public ActionResult Index()
           {
               _logger.LogInformation("Log message in the Index() method");
               return View();
           }
   }
   ```
3. After updating the Nuget packages, you can run your application where you can observe that telemetry will be submitted to Application Insights when you navigate the site's pages.

If Adding Application Insights Automatically isn't working, then you can try manually from  [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-manually).

**REFERENCE :**

1. [Configure monitoring for ASP.NET with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-automatically)
2. [azure - Application Insights for WebAPI application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316825/application-insights-for-webapi-application/62148669#62148669)
3. [Logger.LogTrace() does not write message to application insights](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/845)

Comment: Thanks for your response, above solution works well if singleton pattern is implemented, but if singleton pattern is not present then we can solve this using TelemetryClient

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to resolve this issue.

1. Navigate to your Project >> Add Application Insights Telemetry >> Application Insights Sdk (local) >> Next >> Finish >> Close.
2. In the Global.asax.cs add below line

   TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
3. Wherever wanted to add application insights add below code, you can create common logger file also.

   ```
       TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
       client.TrackTrace("Custom Track Trace");

       client.TrackAvailability(new AvailabilityTelemetry() { Name = "Availablilty Test"});
       client.TrackDependency(new DependencyTelemetry() { Name = "Dependency Test" });
       client.TrackEvent(new EventTelemetry() { Name = "Event Test" });
       client.TrackException(new ExceptionTelemetry() { Message = "Exception Test" });
       client.TrackMetric(new MetricTelemetry() { Name = "Metric Test" });
       client.TrackPageView(new PageViewTelemetry() { Name = "PageView Test" });
       client.TrackRequest(new RequestTelemetry() { Name = "Request Test" });
   ```